# Performance optimization of a database access query in Python/Django web app

Tags: python, django, database, performance, postgresql

**TL;DR**

In a Django app I maintain, I'm making a DB call from inside a FOR loop. Bad idea; I want to take this outside the loop. Here's the code:

```
for link in context["object_list"]:
        try:
            latest_reply = link.publicreply_set.latest('submitted_on')
            #if latest_reply is something:
               #do something
        except:
            pass
```

What would be the DB call outside the FOR loop? As you can see, I'm trying to get the **latest** `publicreply` for each `link` object (foreign key relationship). Note that a `publicreply` may not exist for every `link` object.  I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do this outside the loop. Profiling tells me this repeated call adds significant overhead.

---

**More details:**

Models are:

```
class Link(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(500)])
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Publicreply(models.Model):
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    answer_to = models.ForeignKey(Link)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(250)])

class Seen(models.Model):
    seen_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    seen_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    seen_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    which_reply = models.ForeignKey(Publicreply, related_name="publicreply_seen_related")
```

And adding some more accompanying code to the snippet at the top:

```
link_ids = [link.id for link in context["object_list"]]
seen_replies = Publicreply.objects.filter(answer_to_id__in=link_ids,publicreply_seen_related__seen_user = user)
for link in context["object_list"]:
        try:
            latest_reply = link.publicreply_set.latest('submitted_on')
            if latest_reply in seen_replies:
               #do something
        except:
            pass
```

Lastly, `context["object_list"]` is a list of `link` objects. For each `link` object shown in the Django template, if it has a `latest_reply`, I'll compare it to some timestamp and put in visual markers if certain conditions are true.

Comment: can you describe context, and models?

Comment: hang on, I'll edit the question

Comment: @Codeboy.ru: gave more details. What do you think?

Comment: I think ... still think ... I think it kinda weard ))

Comment: The way I'm trying to solve it is weird, or trying to formulate an answer to my question is weird?

Comment: hmmm ... i get - FieldError
Cannot resolve keyword 'publicreply_seen_related' into field

Comment: Hey note that under `class Seen`, `which_reply = models.ForeignKey(Publicreply, related_name="publicreply_seen_related")`  has a `related_name` defined in there. Maybe you missed that.

Comment: Any luck Codeboy.ru?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
latest_replys = Publicreply.objects.all().order_by('answer_to','-submitted_on').distinct('answer_to')

for reply in latest_replys:
    if reply in in seen_replies:
        #do something
```

Comment: Intriguing. let me get back to you on this.

Comment: Sadly I get `DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend`. Locally, I'm on SQLite, it seems distinct on doesn't work there.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to pull in `latest_replys = Publicreply.objects.all().order_by('answer_to','-submitted_on')` and then execute the **distinct** functionality in memory? That would be a better reply in my particular case, since that would be database agnostic.

Comment: My answer would work on a postgres sql DB. If you just pull `latest_replys = Publicreply.objects.all().order_by('answer_to','-submitted_on')` and then trying to find the distinct latest replys without using  `distinct()` may require **for looping , grouping etc** which would again reduce performance.

Comment: You're right, it's still going to be a performance nightmare. I suppose it's high time I install Postgres in my local environment too then.

Comment: Yes its always better to have same setup's in local and your live server....So could you please accept my answer...thanks!

Comment: Yea Anush I will, give me a bit to test it. Your answer makes a lot of sense. Thanks buddy!